# Tomcat webapp: resource bundle variable not working

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have a webapp on Tomcat 6 using JSP and JSF. The problem is that it is not using the variable bound to a resource bundle correctly. The code from the JSP file:

```
<f:loadBundle basename="ApplicationResources" var="msg" />

<h:outputFormat value="#{msg.myvar}" escape="false"></h:outputFormat>
```

The output to the web page is simply the text "#{msg.myvar}".

I have enabled logging and it appears to be locating and loading the bundle correctly. I have tried different variables in the bundle but it didn't make a difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be ${msg.myvar} and not #{msg.myvar} (dollar sign and not pound sign)?

Comment: The pound sign is usually used for entries in properties file (ex: for localization). That's, I'm guessing, what he means by resource bundle.

Comment: Yes, the data is in a properties file.